# Access Violation if RTTI is accessed inside package

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe2, rtti

I wrote a simple console program to cast some RTTI magic:

```
program TypeCast;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.RTTI, Generics.Collections;

type
  TSpr = class
  public
    s: string;
    i: Integer;
    b: Boolean;
  end;

var
  Spr: TSpr;
  vCtx: TRTTIContext;
  vType: TRTTIType;
  vField: TRTTIField;
  Dict: TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>;

begin
  try
    Spr := TSpr.Create;
    vType := vCtx.GetType(TSpr.ClassInfo);
    Dict := TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>.Create;
    for vField in vType.GetFields do
      Dict.AddOrSetValue(vField.Name, vField);
    Dict['s'].SetValue(Spr, 'Hello World!');
    Dict['i'].SetValue(Spr, 123);
    Dict['b'].SetValue(Spr, True);
    Writeln(Spr.s);
    Writeln(Spr.i);
    Writeln(Spr.b);
    Spr.Free;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> Hello World!
> 123
> TRUE
> ```

If I compile and run this program, it works fine. But if I use such technique to forward variables of these types to object, defined in another package, it gets me into lot of troubles.

**MCVE stuff / Steps To Reproduce:**
<sup>*...assuming you are starting from empty environment...*</sup>

1. Create `PluginInterface` package. Add there `UClassManager`

   ```
   unit UClassManager;

   interface

   uses
     Classes, Contnrs;

   type
     TClassManager = class(TClassList);

   function ClassManager: TClassManager;

   implementation

   var
     Manager: TClassManager;

   function ClassManager: TClassManager;
   begin
     Result := Manager;
   end;

   initialization
   Manager := TClassManager.Create;

   finalization
   Manager.Free;

   end.
   ```

   and `UPlugin` units.

   ```
   unit UPlugin;

   interface

   uses RTTI;

   type
     TPlugin = class
     public
       procedure Init; virtual; abstract;
       function SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean; virtual; abstract;
     end;

     TPluginClass = class of TPlugin;
     IPluginHost = interface
       function RunPlugin(PluginName: string): TPlugin; // Run Plugin by it's ClassName
     end;

   var
     Host: IPluginHost;

   implementation

   end.
   ```
2. Create `VCL Forms Application`, enable runtime packages, add reference to `PluginInterface` and add TButton onto it. Make these handlers for corresponding events:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     LoadPackage('UniversalSpr.bpl');
     Host := Self;
   end;

   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     Plugin: TPlugin;
   begin
     Plugin := Host.RunPlugin('TSprPlugin');
     Plugin.Init;
     Plugin.SetProp('SprTableName', 'MATERIALS');
     Plugin.SetProp('EditRights', True);
     Plugin.SetProp('BeforePostValue1', 3);
   end;

   function TForm1.RunPlugin(PluginName: string): TPlugin;
   var
     I: Integer;
   begin
     Result := nil;
     for I := 0 to ClassManager.Count - 1 do
       if ClassManager[I].ClassNameIs(PluginName) then begin
         Result := TPluginClass(ClassManager[I]).Create;
         Break;
       end;
   end;
   ```

   Of coarse, `TForm1` should be descendant of `IPluginHost`. And don't forget to add `UClassManager` and `UPlugin` into `uses` clause. Other units will be added automatically by IDE.
3. Create package `UniversalSpr` and place it's output file into the same directory where your application is placed. Implement `UPlugin` inside `TSprPlugin`:

   ```
   unit USprPlugin;

   interface

   uses
     UPlugin, RTTI, Generics.Collections;

   type
     TSpr = class
       SprTableName: string;
       BeforePostValue1: int64;
       EditRights: boolean;
     end;
     TSprPlugin = class(TPlugin)
       procedure Init; override;
       function SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean; override;
       private
         Spr: TSpr;
         PropDict: TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>;
     end;

   implementation

   procedure TSprPlugin.Init;
   var
     vCtx: TRTTIContext;
     vType: TRTTIType;
     vField: TRTTIField;
   begin
     if not Assigned(Spr) then
       Spr := TSpr.Create;
     vType := vCtx.GetType(Spr.ClassInfo);
     if not Assigned(PropDict) then
       PropDict := TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>.Create;
     for vField in vType.GetFields do
       PropDict.Add(vField.Name, vField);
   end;

   function TSprPlugin.SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean;
   var
     Field: TRTTIField;
   begin
     Result := PropDict.TryGetValue(Key, Field);
     if Result then
       // here I get Access Violation
       Field.SetValue(Spr, Value);
   end;

   end.
   ```

After you click `Button1`, you can pass specified values into properties setter/mutator, but if you try to repeat my `TypeCast` trick inside the routine, you'll get Access Violation trying to access `00000004`.

Also, investigation and advanced debugging shows that `Field.FieldType` evaluates correctly (which explains why InsufficientRTTI is not thrown), but if I want to get `Field.Fieldtype.Handle`, I get the infamous AV.

I can set the value just skipping `Cast` from original `SetValue` method:

```
function TSprPlugin.SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean;
var
  Field: TRTTIField;
begin
  Result := PropDict.TryGetValue(Key, Field);
  if Result then
    Value.ExtractRawData(PByte(Spr) + Field.Offset);
end;
```

Dalija recommended to avoid packages, I already took this into accout, that's why I created `TypeCast` to test RTTI. But I need packages, because of design of my application, I cannot just rewrite it to be monolythic. What can I do to avoid this Access Violation *without abandoning packages*?

Comment: What's not clear from this is how the packages are arranged. I'd expect that any attempt to perform RTTI on a type defined in a different package would fail. Have you considered doing some debugging to identify which line of code fails, and which reference is `nil`?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to write `vCtx := TRTTIContext.Create`, you can remove that line. A `TRttiContext` variable is automatically initialised. And you don't need `vCtx.Free`, you can remove that line.

Comment: Hmm, I claim that `USprPlugin` and `UniversalSprUnit` use the same package, it is `UniversalSpr`. And by debugging I found that I can read `PropDict[Key]`'s properties except `FieldType`.

Comment: Another btw, don't test `ContainsKey` and then `GetValue`. That performs two lookups. Do it in one with `TryGetValue`.

Comment: It's still not clear to me which line of code leads to the access violation. Do you know?

Comment: I marked the line: `if Result then
      // here I get Access Violation
      PropDict[Key].SetValue(Spr, Value);`
and I think it fails because it can't access FieldType.

Comment: I can't see `if Result then` in the question. I give up. Never mind.

Comment: Sorry, @David, can't make it any clearer. Btw, you need the line `PropDict[Key].SetValue(Spr, Value);`. And I implemented all your suggestions in my working copy and testing it now. Thanks for them!

Comment: OK, I see it in the updated question. So, which reference is `nil`. I do wonder how much debugging you have done. An access violation like this will break in the debugger. You can inspect the values. Even if you cannot use the interactive debugger, you can use trace debugging. It seems to me that the art of debugging is so often neglected. I'd say that a very significant proportion of questions here are asked simply because the asker has not learnt sufficient debugging skills. My no. 1 piece of advice to you is to seek to improve your debugging skills.

Comment: Hmm, as I already said, I found the line... I watched the sources and determined that evaluation of `PropDict[Key].FieldType` raises AV. It is not used in listing here, but I tried to inline the `SetValue` method, and found out that roots are growing from this `FieldType`. Evaluating `PropDict[Key].FieldType` in Evaluate/Modify dialog fails too.

Comment: So, which reference is `nil`?

Comment: Haha, I'm in doubts... I tried to debug with debug dcu's and it seems that actual calling sequence is far from the one which I can explore by Ctrl-Click. I will report if I'll find something important.

Comment: There is vital part of code missing here: `UClassManager` Also there is too much irrelevant code included. Please provide mcve - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I deleted almost all the irrelevant stuff and added some clarification, please check

Comment: You have deleted some irrelevant stuff, but that is far from proper MCVE. You failed to create minimal example, there is still plenty of cruft left, but most important you have failed to create complete and verifiable example. I cannot take your code and compile it as-is without doing a lot of guessing. Saying `ClassManager` is simple class list does not cut it. How do you populate it, how do you initialize host, how do you find plugin from its name. That is all relevant information where your real issue may be hiding.

Comment: However, issue is not in information you have failed to provide. You are caching context information that gets lost later on in `TSprPlugin.Init;` move `vCtx` declaration from local var to `TSprPlugin` class member and don't `Free` it until your `TSpPlugin` instance is alive. That should resolve the error.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I fail to `SetValue` even inside `Init`.

Comment: Ok, you have done some progress in providing MCVE, but can you add uses list for your test application (with Form1), namely following your steps `LoadPackage('UniversalSpr.bpl');` currently achieves nothing and `Host.RunPlugin('TSprPlugin')` returns `nil`. Having said that I can see some obvious errors in your code, but I still cannot reproduce your issue as you see it.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has some issues regardless whether you use runtime packages or not. Your MCVE is not exactly minimal, and you have added too many steps from your working console application to your packaged code that does not work.

In debugging your issue you should have started from encapsulating logic into `TSprPlugin` class and testing that class directly without messing with runtime packages. When you are sure that `TSprPlugin` code functions properly, then you can add packages and see how it goes.

Right now your code fails with following simple test project

```
program test;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  USprPlugin in 'USprPlugin.pas',
  UPlugin in 'UPlugin.pas';

var
  Plugin: TPlugin;

begin
  Plugin := TSprPlugin.Create;
  Plugin.Init;

  Plugin.SetProp('SprTableName', 'MATERIALS');
  Plugin.SetProp('EditRights', True);
  Plugin.SetProp('BeforePostValue1', 3);
end.
```

Moving `vCtx` from local variable to `TSprPlugin` field solves the issue for above test case.

```
unit USprPlugin;

interface

uses
  UPlugin, RTTI, UniversalSprUnit, Generics.Collections;

type
  TSprPlugin = class(TPlugin)
    vCtx: TRTTIContext;
    procedure Init; override;
    function SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean; override;
    private
      Spr: TSpr;
      PropDict: TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>;
  end;

implementation

procedure TSprPlugin.Init;
var
  vType: TRTTIType;
  vField: TRTTIField;
begin
  vCtx := TRttiContext.Create;
  if not Assigned(Spr) then
    Spr := TSpr.Create;
  vType := vCtx.GetType(Spr.ClassInfo);
  if not Assigned(PropDict) then
    PropDict := TDictionary<string, TRTTIField>.Create;
  for vField in vType.GetFields do
    PropDict.Add(vField.Name, vField);
end;

function TSprPlugin.SetProp(Key: string; Value: TValue): Boolean;
var
  Field: TRTTIField;
begin
  Result := PropDict.TryGetValue(Key, Field);
  if Result then
    // here I get Access Violation
    Field.SetValue(Spr, Value);
end;

end.
```

Starting from there you can add up additional functionality step by step ensuring that each step didn't break functionality.

Also, you are not releasing `Spr` and `PropDict` fields thus creating memory leak, but I am not sure if that code is not included just because it is not directly connected with issues you are having, or you are really having memory leak there.

Comment: Actually, TRTTIContext is **record**, not **class**, so I think it doesn't need to be explicitly created. The problem appears when I introduce packages, and I can't simply avoid them, I have a lot of code written in plugin paradigm. Also, I initially invoked `vCtx.Free` just before setting s, i, b in `TypeCast` program. I can assume that freeing object doesn't actually erases it, but let me be picky: records *are not* created explicitly,

Comment: It is record, so its memory does not have to be allocated with `Create`, but that does not mean other initialization can be omitted. the same way `Free` can render data in record invalid even though record will still exist in memory. I prefer following the documentation in this case. [Obtaining RTTI Context](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Obtaining_the_RTTI_Context)